# Google apps script authorization - have to call scripts twice?

Tags: google-apps-script

I was wondering if there was a way to run a script requiring authorization without having to call it twice.  For example, if I have a link on my google site that calls a script, I have to click on it two times - once to begin the authorization process, and once to actually run the script afterwards.  I feel like this would be very confusing to users.

Thanks!
Jeff

Comment: It's even worse than that.  If you use UrlFetchApp to call a service that requires OAuth, you have to run the script 3 times!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to avoid this but I've found that it was generally less confusing to create a dummy function (that I usually call 'Authorize') that has to be called once and that does nothing else than trigger the authorization process and show a small explanation text. This makes things probably more clear for a 'normal' user as it is a separate process and not a repetition that gives the feeling something is wrong...